# How to confirm that drush-based cron is being called from crontab?

Tags: 8, drush, cron

I don’t know whether this is a docksal-specific question or a general cron one, but likely the latter.

I’ve set up a crontab for docksal (see https://blog.docksal.io/running-scheduled-events-with-docksal-43fc69d7b29b):

`0 */3 * * * drush --root="/var/www/docroot" core-cron`

My question is how tell if it’s actually working. I don’t see anything logged in at `/admin/reports/dblog`. I also tried enabling the syslog module, but I’m not seeing a syslog file at `/var/log` as described, using `fin bash` and `cd`ing to that directory.

I don't whether I should expect to see something, but would prefer I did. Otherwise it's like trying to check if the refrigerator light has gone off when you've closed the door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've answered your own question. Viewing the admin DB log reports or running something like `fin drush wd-show --type=cron` should show cron execution entries. If you're ***not seeing*** those logs, it most likely means the crontab config isn't working.

You should check `drush --root="/var/www/docroot" core-cron` works correctly when manually executed in the container where crontab is configured (e.g. perhaps the crontab user doesn't have `drush` available in its path or drush can't find the DB config) & the `/var/log/` dir (it will depend on the Linux distro the Docksal image is based on) for cron logs to confirm that its firing.

Comment: I did run `drush --root="/var/www/docroot" core-cron` and the results were displayed in the dblog, so I think you're right, and the answer to my question is "yes." There were messages during that indicating that perhaps a syslog file couldn't be generated due to permissions, but that's off topic. Thanks!